# App Engine no longer updating index.yaml

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

The index.yaml file of my GAE app is no longer updated by the development server. 
I have recently added a new kind to my app and a handler that queries this kind like so:

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb

class MyKind(ndb.Model):
    thing = ndb.TextProperty()
    timestamp = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
```

and in the handler I have a query

```
query = MyKind.query()
query.order(-MyKind.timestamp)
logging.info(query.iter().index_list())
entities = query.fetch(100)
for entity in entities:
    # do something
```

AFAIK, the development server should create an index for this query and update index.yaml accordingly. However, it doesn't.  It just looks like this:

```
indexes:

# AUTOGENERATED
```

The `logging.info(query.iter().index_list())` should output the index used for the query, it just says 'None'. Also, the SDK console says 'Datastore contains no indexes.'

Running the query returns the entities unsorted. I have two questions:

- is there some syntax error in my code causes the query results be unsorted or is it the missing index?
- if it's the missing index, is there a way to manually force the dev server to update index.yaml? Other suggestions?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your call to order returns the new query..

```
query = MyKind.query()
query = query.order(-MyKind.timestamp)
```

..to clarify..

query.order(-MyKind.timestamp) does not change the query, it returns a new one, so you need to use the query returned by that method. As it is query.order(-MyKind.timestamp) in your code does nothing.

Comment: thanks! I have clarified the question: I would like to know what I have to do in order to make my query results sorted.

Comment: use the query returned by query.order(). as it is you are still using the unordered query. The ordered query is thrown to the ether. So change your two lines to the lines I provided.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Query is working fine now and apparently doesn't need an index